# Accessing subclass arguments

Tags: c++, inheritance, subclass

I recently added a subclass Enemy to my Character class which takes in two more parameters in its constructor.

```
Enemy::Enemy(const string &name, int health, int stamina, bool _isEnemy, bool _roaming) : Character(name, health, stamina), isEnemy(_isEnemy), roaming(_roaming){
    this->name = name;
    this->stamina = stamina;
    this->isEnemy = _isEnemy;
    this->roaming = _roaming;
```

My character class also has getters and setters for health stamina and currentroom. In my main then I have a a vector of pointers of type Enemy and I just use a simple for loop to choose and enemy and call a specific function like getCurrentRoom()

```
for(int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {
            if(currentRoom == enemies[i]->getCurrentRoom()) {
                cout << enemies[i]->getName() << " HP: " << enemies[i]->getHealth() << " " << enemies[i]->getName()
                     << " ST: " << enemies[i]->getStamina() << endl;
            }
```

This just displays the Enemies HP and ST if they are in the same room as the player. But when debugging to see the values of enemy[0] for example it has[Character object which I'm guessing is there due to it being the base class but also values from its own Enemy class with incorrect health and it is unable to access its current room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SS8xa.png)

The getCurrentRoom() simply returns a pointer of type room. Would the reason the subclass hasn't got access is because the pointer it returns is under private in Character.h?

Comment: Did you forgot to inherit with public keyword?

Comment: No have it set to  inherit public. When looking through the debugger the values of the the enemy when under the character constructor are wrong but character constructor is able to access the enemies current room. While under the enemy constructor it is unable to access memory address of its current room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `getters` and `setters` declared in the `Character` class are public and not pure virtual, and the `Enemy` class publicly inherits from Character, like so:

```
class Enemy : public Character
```

the `Enemy` class does not need (and should not have) `getters` and `setters` for the name, health and stamina variables. Check these conditions are true.

Also, looking at your implementation of the `Enemy` class constructor, assuming the `Character` constructor already sets name, health and stamina, you do not need to set it again in the body of your `Enemy` constructor (assuming you do not have another three variables declared in your `Enemy` class called name, health and stamina, which is a design flaw if you do).

One other thing, you are passing the name variable by value through the `Enemy` constructor. To prevent needless copying, and therefore produce more efficient code, pass it by constant reference, or `std::move` it into the `Character` constructor, depending on whether the `Character` constructor also passes the name variable by value or not. This is not necessary for the health and stamina variables, as they are trivially copy-constructible and move-constructible.

To summarize, if your `Character` constructor is declared like so:

```
Character::Character(string name, int health, int stamina);
```

modify your `Enemy` constructor to:

```
Enemy::Enemy(string name, int health, int stamina, bool _isEnemy, bool _roaming) : Character(std::move(name), health, stamina), isEnemy(_isEnemy), roaming(_romaing){
}
```

This will require you to move the name argument in the `Character` constructor into the name member of the `Character` class also, if that has not already been done.

EDIT:

To make use of inheritance, this is what the Character class and Enemy class should look like, with respect to the code snippets above:

```
//Character class 

class Character{
    private:
        //private data members
        std::string name;
        int health;
        int stamina;

    public:
        //constructor
        Character(const std::string& _name, int _health, int _stamina);

        //getters
        int get_health() const;
        int get_stamina();
        std::string get_name() const;

        //setters
        void set_health(int _health);
        void set_stamina(int _stamina);
        void set_name(const std::string& _name);
};

//Enemy class

//public inheritance from Character
class Enemy: public Character{
    private:
        //private data members
        bool isEnemy;
        bool roaming;

    public:
        //public constructor
        Enemy(const std::string& name, int health, int stamina, 
            bool _isEnemy, bool _roaming);
};

//Character class implementation

//set private data members in constructor
Character::Character(const std::string& _name, int _health, int _stamina)
          : name(_name), health(_health), stamina(_stamina){
}

//simple getter definitions 
int Character::get_health() const {
    return health;
}

int Character::get_stamina() const {
    return stamina;
}

std::string Character::get_name() const {
    return name;
}

//simple setters definitions
void Character::set_health(int _health) {
    health = _health;
}

void Character::set_stamina(int _stamina) {
    stamina = _stamina;
}

void Character::set_name(const std::string& _name) {
    name = _name;
}

//Enemy class implementation

//call character constructor, and set other private data members
Enemy(const std::string& name, int health, int stamina, 
        bool _isEnemy, bool _roaming) : Character(name, health, stamina),
        isEnemy(_isEnemy), roaming(_roaming){
}
```

Note: You may want to implement `getters` and `setters` for `roaming` and `isEnemy` in the `Enemy` class, in a similar manner to the `getters` and `setters` in the Character class.

Notice how name, stamina and health are not re-declared in the Enemy class. This is because they already exist in the Character class, from which Enemy inherits. If you want to get or set name, health or stamina, use public getters and setters from character class. You would use them like so:

```
Enemy dragonEnemy("Dragon", 100, 50, true, true);

//using public getter
int dragonHealth = dragonEnemy.get_health();

//using public setter
dragonEnemy.set_stamina(55);
```

Comment: thanks made the changes. In the modified Enemy constructor, whats the purpose of `isEnemy(_isEnemy)` and `roaming(_roaming)` instead of leaving them two out altogether?

I'm still unsure of the whole subclass calling to base class constructor as my enemies are still unable to access the memory address when getting their current room. The get current room function in Character returns a pointer of type Room and I just use a simple for loop to traverse through the vector of Enemy pointers and call the method.

Comment: isEnemy(_isEnemy) and roaming(_roaming) is the equivalent of having this->isEnemy = _isEnemy and this->roaming = _roaming in the constructor. That was from your code snippet. It doesn't make a big deal for boolean variables, but typically speaking, its more efficient to do it that way. As for your original problem, are you sure the getters and setters in the base class are public? If so, I suspect the issue may be a different one. Can you give a snippet of the error you recieve?

Comment: Updated my question. I do however have overriden the setHealth() function in Character class by Putting one in the subclass and altering it a little and then putting "virtual" before the parent class function. Is it possible to set the values in the subclass and then get the values from the parent class?

Comment: @Mikel112543 An issue I see in your code, is you have name, health and stamina variables in both the Character class, and the Enemy class. This defeats the purpose of inheritance, and as mentioned in my original answer, is a design flaw. I've edited my original answer to show what the Character class and Enemy class should look like, with respect to the code snippets you have shown above.

Comment: Oh yes I see I was essentially initializing the variables in the subclass when they  had already been initialized in the parent. Thanks! But I have also recently overriden the setter for Health in Character class, does that mean I must also override the getter for health as the enemies health is not changing when calling the override function?

Comment: @Mikel112543 The issue is you have two sets of name, health and stamina variables for the Enemy class. See my latest edit for explanation.

Comment: Ah I see its working correctly now. Thanks! Also removed the original setHealth override I had for Enemy as it was just unnecessary. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! Feel free to accept my answer to help anybody else with a similar problem.